Trouble with change text in tk.Entry on validation
I want to create an entry field for a date. I want the user to be able to type the digits for the month, day, year and have the '/' come up automatically. I thought I would be able to do this with validation and here's my code:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
     self.grid_propagate(False)

     reg = self.register(self.validate_date)
     tk.Entry(self,name='the_entry', validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P')).grid(row=0, column=1,sticky='E')

def validate_date(self,input):
    
    if input=='':
        return True
    
    if not input[-1].isdigit():
        return False
    
    if len(input)==10:
        return False
    
    if len(input) in [2,5]:
        
        self.nametowidget('the_entry').delete(0,tk.END)
        self.nametowidget('the_entry').insert(0,input + '/')
        

    return True

But what happens is I get one '/' and after that it stops calling the validation function. I've tried re-assigning the validation function with the following code in the if statement:
        self.nametowidget('the_entry').config(validate="key")
        self.nametowidget('the_entry').config(validatecommand= 
(self.register(self.validate_date), '%P'))

When I do that it no longer is adding the '/'.
Can anyone recommend a better way to get the behavior I'm looking for?

It may be because you modify the content of the entry inside the validate command that breaks the validation handling.

I've attempted to fix the formatting here, but you seem to have some missing imports (I assume from __init__ is not intended) and indentation issues in the second block.

Thank you.  That should have been def init.  I only copied it over wrong.
